# flipcard animation by using touch event

Tags: android, android-fragments, gesture, flipview

I am trying to create a flip card animation using setOnTouchListener() on fragment. For this i am folowing Joerock's Xamarin tutorials.Below is my code.. When i am trying to run, front card is displaying, but when i am double tapping on fragment, it is not responding..Please help me where i went wrong..

```
public class OpenClass extends Activity {

private boolean mShowingBack;
public GestureDetector mGestureDetector;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //int gotBread;
    //Bundle gotBasket=getIntent().getExtras();
    //gotBread=gotBasket.getInt("key");

    setContentView(R.layout.flashframe);
    mGestureDetector=new GestureDetector(this, new MyGestureListener(this));

    if(savedInstanceState==null){
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new CardFrontFragment()).commit();
    }

    }
public void flipCard(){
    if(mShowingBack){
    getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    mShowingBack=false;
    return;
    }
    else{
        FragmentTransaction transaction=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.card_flip_right_in, R.animator.card_flip_right_out,
                R.animator.card_flip_left_in, R.animator.card_flip_left_out);
        transaction.replace(R.id.container, new CardBackFragment());
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
        mShowingBack=true;
    }
}


public class CardFrontFragment extends Fragment implements  OnTouchListener{
    public CardFrontFragment(){
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View frontCard=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1,container,false);
        frontCard.setOnTouchListener(this);
        return frontCard;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //OpenClass parentActivity=(OpenClass) getActivity();
        return mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

    }


}
public class CardBackFragment extends Fragment implements OnTouchListener{
    public CardBackFragment(){
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View backCard=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2,container,false);
        backCard.setOnTouchListener(this);
        return backCard;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //OpenClass parentActivity= (OpenClass) getActivity();
        return mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

    }

}

public class MyGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

    private OpenClass mMainActivity;

    public MyGestureListener(OpenClass activity){
    mMainActivity = activity;   
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mMainActivity.flipCard();
        return true;
    }



}
}
```

Comment: Is onDoubleTap() called? Can you add a log to check this? When you say not responding, you mean nothing happens or it crashes?

Comment: nothing happens.. please see my logcat..

Comment: 02-24 00:17:03.370: W/EGL_emulation(825): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-24 00:17:03.430: D/OpenGLRenderer(825): Enabling debug mode 0
02-24 00:17:05.970: W/EGL_emulation(825): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-24 00:17:47.681: W/EGL_emulation(825): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-24 00:17:51.361: W/EGL_emulation(825): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented

Comment: Have you added logs in onDoubleTap() method as I suggested in order to to figure out if the problem comes from the touchListener / gestureListener or the flip logic?

Comment: i added logs in onDouleTap() and in touchlistener(). nothing is happening after front card display. I think inflated view is not wiring touchlistener with it.This is the last message...02-24 08:04:47.155: I/ActivityManager(165): Displayed com.example.nanihere/.OpenClass: +936ms

Comment: can any one please help me..how to  wire touch event to inflated view..

Comment: Can you update your question with the code with logging and add the logcat result after running it so we can see what is called and what isn't?

Comment: You might want to edit your question and post the logcat in there, rather than in the comment. For one thing, it will be formatted much more clearly (and not truncated). Also, this will bump your question to the top of the queue so more people can see it and answer.